# React Native developer menu not responding

Tags: react-native

When I open up the developer menu (either cmd+d or cdm+ctr+z) none of the buttons work. I can't even close the developer menu. It does seem to close after a minute or so, so I don't think it's freezing or crashing, but everything in the app is frozen out for another minute and I have to reset it a few times.

I also tried downgrading react and react-native from 15.1 and 0.28 to 15.0.2 and 0.26, respectively. XCODE is fully up to date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I had the same problem a few weeks ago. All the menus were very slow and Facebook login/logout were taking forever making me think it was frozen.

Turns out I had accidentally turned on the "slow animations" (cmd + T).
Check if it's not the same problem.

[Slow animations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlFUf.png)

Comment: yeah that looks like it did it. Thanks.