# How to keep alert from freezing react-native app on ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, alert, freeze

Alerts have recently stopped working on all my react-native apps on IOS. I have not changed anything other than to update dependencies. They still work fine on android. Specifically, the alert pops up but then the bars separating the buttons on the alert box randomly flash and everything freezes. Around the same time I also had to update my code for all of my react-native apps for the way Picker behaves on android. Maybe it was a coincidence or maybe it was caused by the same update? I updated all of my dependencies at the same time so if that is the issue I'm not sure which one it is.

This happens:

- regardless of whether or not I have a modal component on the page.
- regardless of whether I'm using a javascript alert, the Alert component from react-native, or the AlertIOS component from react-native.

This is just a copy and paste from the official react-native documentation that I'm using on my test page:

```
// Works on both iOS and Android
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
  [
    {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  {cancelable: false},

);
```

Dependencies on App 1:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-print": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
```

Dependencies on App 2:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^1.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^2.0.10",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
```

I do not get any error messages when this happens and nothing unusual appears on the console at all. Also, the buttons do not respond, so in the example above clicking them does not log anything to the console.

Has anyone else run into this and were you able to find the cause? Thanks!

Comment: Update: I suspect that this is actually a problem with my IOS simulator because I now realize I am having the same issue with my developer menu.

Comment: Also, upon closer inspection, it's not that the alerts and pop ups are totally unresponsive. It does respond after several tries.

Comment: Update: I am having the same problem when I try switching to a different IOS simulator. One of the dependencies I updated must not be ok on IOS in general now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all that, it was just that I had accidentally pressed hot keys for slow animations in the simulator. Apparently this change applies to all simulators in XCode if you select it, so switching simulators didn't work because they were both a part of XCode. See these answers for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35116096/9147743

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38189484/9147743